# Retrieving chat messages with AJAX script based on time they were sent

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm building a live chat application with rooms for my assignment. Everything is going great so far, but I'm having trouble properly retrieving the latest chat messages from the database. The messages table has the following fields:

`|    m_id    |    u_id    |    r_id    |    message    |    sent    |`

`m_id` is the primary key. `u_id` and `r_id` are foreign keys to other tables to reference the user who sent the message and the room they sent the message to. The `sent` field has data in PHP's `microtime(true)` format:

```
1326174129.977
```

I've built my AJAX script to retrieve messages from the database and it looks like this:

```
function getMessages() {
    var d = new Date();
    $.post("/ajax/getmessages.php", {roomID: roomID, timestamp: timestamp}, function(resp) {
        resp = $.parseJSON(resp);

        for(x in resp) {
            $('#chat-holder ul').append('<li>[' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + '] <strong>' + resp[x].u_id + '</strong>: ' + resp[x].msg + '</li>');
            $("#chat-holder").scrollTop($("#chat-holder")[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

The `getMessages` function runs once a second, and then when it retieves data back from the `getmessages.php` script it loops through the JSON encoded response and ads list items to the chat frame. Pretty simple.

The problem is, it retrieves all messages sent to the room, not just the ones that have been sent since the last time the user polled for the latest messages. So I end up with every message that's been sent in the chat being added to the chat frame every second.

The only thing I've come up with is to store a timestamp of the last time the user requested the messages, and then use that in my backend PHP script somehow. Unfortunately, I can't quite get my head around how to implement it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the idea isn't so much to get all messages after a given time so much as to get all messages since the previous batch of messages, I think it'd be easier to do this based on your message table's primary key rather than the timestamp field. Create a client-side variable to note the highest (known) id so far:

```
var highestMessageId = 0;
```

Then when you make your ajax request pass that id through to the PHP:

```
$.post("/ajax/getmessages.php", {roomID: roomID, fromMessageId : highestMessageId},
```

Then in your PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE r_id = $r_id
AND   m_id > $m_id
```

In the ajax success handler you then update `highestMessageId` with the id from the last record in the new batch.

Of course this assumes that your table uses a standard numeric key where records added later have a higher key than records added earlier...

EDIT: Now that I think about it exactly the same procedure would work with the timestamp field too. When I started writing the above I thought there was some reason why timestamp wouldn't work, but I think I was just confusing myself worrying about a non-issue (I was thinking about the times of the ajax requests rather than the timestamp on the records).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got the idea right.

```
$.post("/ajax/getmessages.php", {roomID: roomID, timestamp: timestamp},
```

Where does that timestamp come from?

Anyway, on the server you should be doing this (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE r_id = $roomID AND sent > $timestamp
ORDER BY sent;
```

Then you emit that data to client, along with the latest timestamp (`sent` value of the last row).

```
{timestamp: $last_sent,
 messages: [...]
}
```

Then, in your AJAX callback you do this:

```
resp = $.parseJSON(resp);

last_timestamp = resp['timestamp'];

for(x in resp['messages']) {
  // ...
}
```

And then you use `last_timestamp` in next request.

```
    $.post("/ajax/getmessages.php", {roomID: roomID, timestamp: last_timestamp}, ...
```

Go to step 1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add `WHERE created > DATE_SUB(date(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 hour) ORDER BY created` clause to your SQL, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to use timestamp but the id for downloading the newest messages. When you have thousands/millions of messages in your database, this will result a lot better performance.

And also, instead of downloading messages in every second, I would delay it on the server, meaning the server doesn't give a response until at least one new message has arrived. Like this:

```
$start = time();
$query = mysql_query(...);
while(mysql_num_rows($query)==0 && time()-$start < 25) {
   usleep(200000); // we wait for 200 ms so the server won't be overloaded
   $query = mysql_query(...);
}
//print out the results
```

After you get the results on client side, don't delay, make the next request immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Save the last retrieved timestamp in `localstorage`

```
<script>
var last_timestamp=localStorage.getItem('last_timestamp')||1;
$.post("/ajax/getmessages.php", {roomID: roomID, timestamp: last_timestamp}, function(resp) {
        resp = $.parseJSON(resp);
   //save last retrieved id 
localStorage.setItem('last_timestamp', resp.new_timestamp);
.....
</script>
```

And of course, browser must support localStorage for it to work.